# DataTable can't get id element after page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to make ajax call on focus for every text input, I can make is in first page( when document ready) but when I change page , javascript can't parse inputs because it wasn't created when document is ready. How can I fix it ?

```
    jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    jQuery('[id^=urun_sirasi-]').focus(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var urun_sirasi=jQuery(this).data('sira');
    console.log(urun_sirasi);
    jQuery('#urun_sirasi-'+urun_sirasi).bind('keyup',function(e)
    {
       console.log(jQuery("#urun_sirasi-"+urun_sirasi).val());
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'../ajax.php',
            data:'process=siralama&urun_id='+urun_sirasi+'&urun_sirasi='+jQuery.trim(jQuery("#urun_sirasi-"+urun_sirasi).val()),
            success:function(e){
               // e -> 1 ve ya0 geliyor.
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to a very common problem in the jQuery section. See the docs for `.on()` at http://api.jquery.com/on/, specifically the section about delegated events:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following syntax in the doc ready that will create events for all future items with the "expand" class, should be able to be adjusted for you

```
$(document).on('click',"#myTable .expand", function(){
```

so yours should be something like this (maybe give your items a class rather than having an event to each element selector)

```
 $(document).on('keyup',"#yourTable .urun_sirasi-key", function(){
```

Comment: When I change pages, I try to catch items but it didn't work, so I put these on  a function and when ajax callback happens I recall the function so it parsed all items. It works now , thanks for your help